# Unable to copy source code with docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an npm package where we are keeping our common code and publishing it to an internal repository. The package name is `docker-images`. Inside that I have a dockerfile with the following

```
FROM <Our internal base image>

# Setting src variable. 
ARG src

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /home/default
USER root

# Copy the src code
COPY $src /home/default

# Install all the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Change permissions to default user and ensure we enter at the right spot
RUN chown -R default:default /home/default
USER default
```

Also in this package I have a shell script with that does the building

```
OPTIND=1 # Reset getopts in case it was changed in a previous run
while getopts "h::f::s::" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        h)

            exit 1
            ;;

        f)
            dockerfile=$OPTARG
            ;;
        s)
            src=$OPTARG
            ;;
        *)

            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

 docker build --pull=true --build-arg "src=${src}" --tag="latest" --file=${dockerfile} ${src}
```

From another npm package I have a script which calls this script to build it that script does

```
npm install docker-images
PKG_ROOT=$(cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")" && cd ../ && pwd)
./node_modules/docker-images/scripts/publish.sh -f "$PKG_ROOT/node_modules/docker-images/dockerfiles/dockerfile" -s "$PKG_ROOT"
```

However when builds on our jenkins box it gives me the error

```
Step 3 : ARG src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 09e6987081e7
Step 4 : WORKDIR /home/default
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d4f1edf337ca
Step 5 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f5e52439f60f
Step 6 : COPY $src /home/default
lstat home/jenkins-slave/workspace/dockerbuild: no such file or directory
```

I also printed out the command that my shell script is calling which is

```
docker build --pull=true --build-arg src=/home/jenkins-slave/workspace/dockerbuild --file=/home/jenkins-slave/workspace/dockerbuild/node_modules/docker-images/dockerfiles/dockerfile /home/jenkins-slave/workspace/dockerbuild
```

Obviously the path /home/jenkins-slave/workspace/dockerbuild exists since it can find the dockerfile but I don't know why it won't copy the src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths in docker are all relative , so just as an experiment can you try the following where you are copying the source:

```
WORKDIR $src
COPY . /home/default
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rambler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2571455/rambler) is right, the paths need to be relative to the Docker build context, but you don't need to change your Dockerfile, just use a relative path in the `build-arg` value.

With this simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
ARG src
COPY $src .
```

You will get the failure if you use a full path in the argument:

```
> docker build -t temp --build-arg src=/home/scrapbook/tutorial/src .
...
Step 3 : COPY $src .
lstat home/scrapbook/tutorial/src: no such file or directory
```

But if you use a relative path from the build context, the same Dockerfile is fine:

```
> docker build -t temp --build-arg src=./src .
...
Successfully built d4899d51a284
```